# A Q on the python spark streaming example on Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, streaming

I'm following the spark streaming example notebook on the databricks site -  Introduction to Spark Streaming (Python). I wondered how you get the bar chart that is displayed to update automatically. It seems that to update it you need to wait a bit and then re-run the query to update the bar chart. In the Spark Summit videos both Michael Armburst and Greg Owen do something similar but their charts update automatically. How do they get their charts to update automatically ?

Comment: please share example code, it is unclear what is not working for you.

Comment: I think its one of those things where you have to be a databricks community user.  As part of that there are a number of example notebooks that you can run that show various aspects of how SPARK works. See (https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/index.html for example

Comment: Actually here is the link to the example notebook I'm talking about

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/index.html#structured-streaming-python

Answer (score 0):

Ok, apparently this is a restriction of the free community edition. You just cannot run "jobs" using it.